# 'RelationshipProperty' object is not iterable - Flask Api - sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

:)

I develop a Android Cook-App with a Meal price calculation.

I nearly finished my Api but now I get a TypeError: 'RelationshipProperty' object is not iterable.

I struggle with my sum(mealprice) I have my json but I like to query my mealprice with

```
@classmethod
def find_by_mealprice(cls, mealprice):
    return cls.query.filter_by(mealprice=mealprice).first()
```

But I can only build my sum in the json method.

class MealModel(db.Model):

```
__tablename__ = 'meal'

id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(80))
description = db.Column(db.String)
usp = db.Column(db.String)
workTime = db.Column(db.TIME)
mainIngredients =db.Column(db.String)
img = db.Column(db.String)

difficulty_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('difficulty.id'))
difficulty = db.relationship('DifficultyModel')

diet_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('diet.id'))
diet = db.relationship('DietModel')

category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
category = db.relationship('CategoryModel')

recipes = db.relationship('RecipeModel', lazy="dynamic")

mealprice = (sum([(recipe.ingredients.price/recipe.ingredients.minamount * recipe.quantity) for recipe in recipes])) <-- TypeError?


def __repr__(self):
    return (self.name)



def json(self):

    mealprice = (sum([(recipe.ingredients.price/recipe.ingredients.minamount * recipe.quantity) for recipe in self.recipes]))

    return {    'id': self.id, 
                'name': self.name, 
                'mIng': self.mainIngredients, 
                'usp': self.usp,
                'difficulty': self.difficulty.name,
                'workTime': self.workTime.isoformat(),
                'diet': self.diet.name,
                'description': self.description,
                'mealImage': self.img,
                'category': self.category.name,
                'recipes': [recipe.json() for recipe in self.recipes],
                'meal_price': mealprice
            }
```

I hope this Question is not to stupid, I am newish in Flask Api and Python, I startet programming  a few months ago with Android Studio.

I hope you can help! :) How can I query with mealprice??

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

You did not include the column you want to query into your table.

Long answer:

SQLAlchemy helps you convert models that reside in a database to move them into classes in your python code so both can interact pretty magically. You can use python to extend the models generated with SQLAlchemy, just like you did when declaring mealprice and json. You can also overload existing attributes, just like you did with **repr**.

To be able to query an attribute, you have to make it an attribute in the SQLAlchemy sense of the word, and that is a column. When you do:

```
category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
```

You create a category_id attribute in python, based on a db.Column, which is an SQLAlchemy attribute, therefore you can put queries to it.

In other words, if you do:

```
mealprice = db.Column(db.Numeric, default=calc_mealprice, onupdate=calc_mealprice)
```

And you define your function however you like, http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html

That would make your mealprice queryable, since it is now a column. However, you will have problems making your function in your current database state, because your mealprice is the sum of colums inside the results of a query.

The error you recieve, TypeError, is because you're mixing queries with numbers, and they are evaluated after the object has been constructed. So recipe.ingredients.price is a query when you define mealprice (during construction), but becomes a list during json.

## **EDIT:**

Personally, I would keep concerns separate and avoid hybrid attributes for now, because they may blur the limits between the database and python for you. If your ingredients may change, I would do something like:

```
def calc_price_by_minamount(context):
    price = context.get_current_parameters()['price']
    minamount = context.get_current_parameters()['minamount']
    return price / ingredient.minamount

class IngredientModel(db.Model):
    ...
    price_by_minamount = db.Column(db.Numeric,
                                   default=calc_price_by_minamount, 
                                   onupdate=calc_price_by_minamount)

def calc_price(context):
    ingredients = context.get_current_parameters()['ingredients']
    quantity = context.get_current_parameters()['quantity']
    return sum([ingredient.price_by_minamount 
                for ingredient 
                in ingredients]) * quantity

class RecipeModel(db.Model):
    ...
    price = db.Column(db.Numeric, 
                      default=calc_price, 
                      onupdate=calc_price)

def calc_mealprice(context):
    recipes = context.get_current_parameters()['recipes']
    return sum([recipe.price for recipe in recipes])

class MealModel(db.Model):
    ...
    mealprice = db.Column(db.Numeric, 
                          default=calc_mealprice, 
                          onupdate=calc_mealprice)
```

You could start from there to implement hybrid attributes if you want.

Comment: Nice answer, but what happens when the price of an ingredient is updated? Then the mealprice column will be outdated. A better way to solve this is to look into [SQLalchemy's hybrid attributes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html), which behave a bit like columns without actually being columns.

Comment: Oh thanks ! That makes sense :) But how a build a database with a working sum function? Can you give me a simple example with 2 models?

Comment: oh Great, Thnaks a lot S.Comeau! But I get null - When can I use "onupdate"?

Comment: The onupdate is a function that gets triggered when the object is updated, make sure you're using the function, not the result. It is calc_mealprice, not calc_mealprice() http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#python-executed-functions

Comment: Maybe you can't have the functions as members to a class, so try this too

Comment: Oh S.Comeau thanks a lot for your answer but now I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'price' - when I try to update my database with flask-admin

Comment: There, fixed the problem in my example. Enjoy!